# Plotting library with support for scaled printing?

Tags: plot

I'm currently searching for a plotting library which can scale its axis to cm/inch for printing. The problem is that the users sometimes want to print the plots and paint custom curves. To see what it's values are, they measure by hand what values it would have. If the space between two ticks is 1.34cm, measuring this would be impossible without a calculator.

Is there such a plot library where I can tell it to scale its axis in a way that makes it possible to set the space between ticks in cm/inches? Or can I use another plotting library with some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but how about just calculating the corresponding number of *pixels* from the required physical dimension and the dot density of the printer (usually represented as [Dots per inch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch))? Then you can use any plot library, as they usually define their sizes and dimensions in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

As was answered -- just use dpi to convert from pixel to cm/inch and back. For plotting to bitmap or to vector SVG you can use [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) -- GPL plotting library.